# JWT, проверка авторизации с другого сайта

Tags: php, python, django, modx, jwt

Вводные данные: есть сайт на PHP (Modx Revo) на домене example.com. Есть другой сайт-магазин этой же компании на поддомене shop.example.com написан на Python Django, на котором реализована авторизация пользователей через JWT (JSON Web Tokens). Вопрос: реально ли сделать так, чтоб при попытке какого-то действия на сайте example.com, проверять зарегистрирован ли и авторизирован ли в данный момент пользователь на shop.example.com и разрешать или запрещать данное действие и переадресовывать на страницу регистрации/авторизации shop.example.com/registration? Т.е. идея в том, чтоб регистрация пользователей была только в одном месте на shop.example.com.